# Inserting a threaded rod all the way through a tree trunk

Tags: structural, tree

I've been setting up a tall tree for roped climbing using gear similar to what is normally used for rock climbing. The idea is basically just to have a fun way for friends to get up high, look at the view, and feel the awesome feeling of the tree swaying slightly in the wind. The tree is a Norfolk pine, which is a southern Pacific tree with moderately soft wood (harder than most pines). The hardware I've put up so far is a series of stainless steel hangers (the type used for rock climbing) held in with 1/2"x2" stainless lag bolts. If the climber slips and is caught by the rope, then the expected direction of pull on this hardware is down, which is perpendicular to the axis of the bolt. I think they should be extremely strong against a force in this direction, but maybe less bombproof in the case of a hypothetical pull that has a component outward. (See [this old government publication](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/nbstechnologic/nbstechnologicpapert319.pdf) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZwY0LZS4qU) showing testing to failure.) I now have bolts up to a height of about 40'.

Here is a picture from when I had put in bolts to about half this height. The hangers are difficult to see, but they're to the right of the wooden holds, where the rope is running.

[image: tree climbing setup]

It would be nice if the topmost anchor could have an extra margin of safety and be immune to any deterioration due to the tree's future growth or attempts to heal over the holes. I've already backed it up with a Prusik knot, which should be extremely strong, but the nylon will be exposed to the elements and UV and will gradually deteriorate over time. (The deterioration is probably a good thing for the long term, since I don't want the tree to get strangled after I'm dead.)

It seems like the really solid way to beef up the top anchor would be to drill a hole all the way through the trunk along a diameter, and put in a stainless steel threaded rod (maybe 3/8") with bolts. Is this a reasonable option? If so, then what tools would be needed? Can one buy threaded rods cut to length, or would I have to cut it with a hacksaw and smooth off any burrs? I don't own a cut-off saw, and I'm imagining that cutting a thick stainless steel rod with a hand-saw would be a long, strenuous job. Would machine oil such as sewing machine oil be a reasonable lubricant to use while sawing? Would I need to buy a special type of hacksaw blade? Would I expect to go through multiple blades?

I do have an electric drill which I'm able to get up there, but I'm not so sure that it would have enough torque to drill a 1/2" hole all the way through the trunk, which is about a foot in diameter at that point. Would I need to buy a series of long drill bits, like 1/8", 1/4" and 1/2"? Would I need to buy intermediate lengths? I don't imagine there's any such thing as a foot-long 1/8" bit.

Is there a simpler option that wouldn't require a lot of tools that I don't have? (I don't want to use chains, both because they could eventually strangle the tree and because you can't knot a chain, so you can't make a friction knot like a Prusik. Draping chains over the branches is not a great option, because the branches on this tree are only about the diameter of my thumb.)

I wonder if it would be just as good to drill a sort of bolt circle going around the whole circumference of the tree, using the type of hangers I've already been using. This would certainly be much easier to install.

Comment: There are threaded rods, usually about 36 inches(unknown how SS comes).  To cut usually thread a nut pass the cut, then use the nut to clean threads.  You do know that in a few years the tree bark will grow over most of those hangers.

Comment: 2” seems really short. Climbing falls generating 2000 pounds aren’t unheard of, and that’s the low end with a dynamic rope. Also, stainless steel can be more brittle than a galvanized steel… check your specs.

Comment: I'd agree. 2" is fine for holding a cabinet to a 2x4 stud. But that's quite different from a live (and want to stay "live") load of a climber.

Comment: Waaay too many questions in one.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate: That's the reason for the two links I gave, which are the best quantitative info I have available on the strength of this type of screw. The first link gives data and a proportionality between strength and surface area in contact, and based on that I estimate that the strength against an outward pull should be about 5 kN, which is *much* greater than any outward force I expect. I don't expect to take any lead falls on these bolts, only toprope falls, and in any case the force should be almost entirely downward. But yeah, I would like a bigger margin for the top anchor.

Comment: *Also, stainless steel can be more brittle than a galvanized steel* These bolts are vastly overdesigned for my purposes, against a downward pull. Most outdoor climbing anchors are 3/8" bolts, while these are 1/2". Stainless is considered the best for outdoor climbing routes, if the person developing the route can afford it, and I think stainless is necessary here because the tree contains moisture. There's no way the bolts or hangers are going to snap. The only possible mode of failure would be if they come straight out, due to a force with an unexpectedly large component along that axis.

Comment: @crip659: Thanks, that's helpful. I'm not quite understanding what you're describing, but it might be enough of a starting point so I can google to understand it.

Comment: You can get a 17"x 5/8" auger bit  with a 7/16" shank so you'd need a drill with a 1/2" chuck or a brace & bite drill.  You can do it with just one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to answer the main questions here, not trying to hit everything.  I'm also not saying this is a good idea or a bad idea... I know nothing about climbing or the strength of what you are proposing.

First, to drill through the tree, the best option for you is a long paddle/spade bit.

[image: paddle bit]

These come in [lengths of up to 16 inches](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bosch-Daredevil-1-2-in-x-16-in-Spade-Bit-DLSB1005/203274541), so you would just need the one bit with no extension.  Extensions are available if you need more length. You don't need a ton of torque for these because the small paddle at the end is the only thing in contact with the wood.  It's not like a long round bit that contacts the wood more and more as you go deeper.  If it was a 1.5" hole you would want to worry more about torque.  Half inch should be no sweat for any modern drill.

For cutting the steel rod, a plain old hacksaw will be fine.  It doesn't take a lot of strength, but it will take a long time and test your stamina.  If you're only making two cuts so it should be manageable.  An extra blade would be nice incase you accidentally damage the first one, but one should get it done.  A file would also be nice for cleaning up the edges.  One trick you can use is having a nut or two threaded onto the rod before it is cut.  Cut the rod and clean up the edges and then when you remove the nuts, they will help clean out any threads on the end that may have been bent or rolled over.